# CSS style indentation on all subsequent lines with a prefix

Tags: css

I've added a CSS style for notes. It needs to include a text prefix, followed by the note. This is my CSS...

```
.note:before {
    content: "Note: ";  
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
}

.note {
    background-color: #f9fcff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

This results in the CSS Result image below. Note that the second line of text isn't indented in line with the first character of the first line. To summarize, what I want is the "I" in "If" on the first line, to align with the "b" in "between" in the second line. Is this possible?

[image: CSS Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding left padding and absolutely positioning the before:

```css
.note:before {
  content: "Note: ";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;          /* match the top padding below */
  left: 5px;         /* pretend there is 5px left padding to match other padding */
}

.note {
  background-color: #f9fcff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 3.5em;    /* 3.5em should allow enough space for note to sit in */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas imperdiet elit in porttitor posuere. Quisque lacinia nibh tellus, a cursus neque gravida at.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. I've played around with the values a little, as I wanted the "Note" prefix to vertically align with the first line. I've ended up with the following which works perfectly. Thanks a million :-)

.idbsnote:before {
 content: "Note: "; 
 font-weight: bold;
 color: blue;
 padding: 5px;
 position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}

.idbsnote {
 background-color: #f9fcff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 4em;
   position: relative;
}

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)  Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the voting numbers at the top left of the answser.  It will let other users know that your problem has been solved.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Done just that :-)

Answer (score 0):

what you're after is a hanging indent. if you style the note with `padding-left` to the distance you'd like the second line to be indented by, then style `text-indent` to the same amount but negative (which brings the first line back to where it is currently positioned), that should get you what you want. take a look [here](http://www.csstothepoint.com/hangingindent.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but a hanging indent won't work in this case because of the prefix. Pete's answer above is the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

A really fast and simple code sample for what you want to create, although you will have to modify by your self the spaces needed. Also I'm sure there might be a more clever way.

Tip: It depends on your element and it's alignment the spaces that you are going to use. Remember that inside `<pre></pre>` element everything you type appears on your site.

```
<div>
<p>Note: If you want to add comments or replies <pre>
</pre>&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;between Full and Minimal display modes.</p>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

P.S.: `&nbsp` stands for 1 space, `&ensp` stands for 2 spaces and `&emsp` stands for 4 spaces.

P.S.2: Works the same either if you use "Note:" as a CSS before element, or inside the paragraph.